# Symfony3 fosuserbundle overriding registrationForm

Tags: fosuserbundle, default-value

I try to override the RegistrationBundle with adding a postal code.

But in the twig register form, when it loads, the postalcode field is not empty and there is written "user" in the

```
<input type="text">
```

And in the password field, it's not empty too

```
<input type="password">
```

This error occure when I am using "http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/en/register/" but if I run another server like "http://localhost:8001/app_dev.php/en/register/" with port 8001, this error don't occure ! What is the matter ?
[image]

Could you explain me why ?

Hi Thanks for your comment. So, I overrided my FOSUserBundle Controller too ! Here is my Form :

```
private $em;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->em = $options['em'];
    $builder            
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
        ->add('postalcode', TextType::class, array(
                                                'attr'=> array('class'=>'postalcode form-control', 
                                                                'maxlength'=>4,
                                                                'value'=>''))
                                            )
        ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, array(
                                'attr'=>array('class'=>'city form-control')))
        ->add('conditions', CheckboxType::class, array('required' => true))
            ;
    $city = function(FormInterface $form, $codepostal){

        $localitestofind = $this->em->findBy(array('codepostal'=>$codepostal));
        $localites = array();

        if($localitestofind)
        {
            foreach($localitestofind as $localitetofind)
            {
                $localites[$localitetofind->getNom()] = $localitetofind->getNom();
            }
        }
        $form->add('city', ChoiceType::class, array(
                                'attr'=>array('class'=>'city form-control'), 
                                'choices'=> $localites));
    };
    $builder->get('postalcode')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($city){
        $city($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
    });
}
```

Your right, but I don't know why my browser autocomplete both fields. I removed the cache of the browser, I removed cookies, ... And I don't have this problem on an other port (8000 vs 8001)

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Can you post your registration form? Without it it's hard to imagine what is happening. But it's seems that browser autocompletes username and password. Why is it autocomplete in code postal I don't know because there is no code example.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why the postalcode is registered in the firefox password registration and not other input values.